# Delete row from mysql table where value not like

Tags: mysql, where-clause, delete-row

I have a table that has the results of tests.
It looks like:

```
Test    | Result
Math    | Pass
Science | Fail
History | cancelled
French  | Absent
```

The table is named table1. I want to delete rows in the table where the value of the column result is not `"Pass"` or `"fail"`

Something like:

```
Delete from table1
where result not in (Pass, Fail);
```

The resulting table would look like:

```
Test    | Result
Math    | Pass
Science | Fail
```

Comment: You're close; just add single quotes around the values: `Delete from table1 where result not in ('Pass', 'Fail')`.

Comment: Yup, your query is fine - you just need to pass in strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example worked for me by adding quotes around `Pass` and `Fail`.

```
delete from table1
where result not in ('Pass', 'Fail')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE result NOT IN ('Pass', 'Fail');
```